# Undefined Method `acts_as_messageable_messages_path`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, message

I'm using [acts-as-messageable](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable), a rails gem, in an app i have.

However in my messages_controller i have

```
def new 
  @message = ActsAsMessageable::Message.new
end
```

and in my view i have

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
```

which throws the following error

> undefined method `acts_as_messageable_messages_path'

I'm not really sure why this is happening with the gem.

Comment: Please post link to the gem's github homepage that you're using.

Comment: @Planetpluto Please see my answer below to see if that method will work instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly stating what path you want the form to point towards (which should be the `messages#create` action):

```
<%= form_for(@message) :url => messages_path, :method => :post do |f| %> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :to %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :to %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :topic %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :topic %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn primary">Send</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
<% end %>
```

This assumes that you have this in your `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :messages
```

Also, make sure you are passing in the required fields to **ActsAsMessageable**:  https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable/wiki/Example-controller

Comment: This solved the error, however the :to param isn't sending. Meaning that when I have @to = User.find_by_email(params[:to]) i get an error, since it doesn't return the user

Comment: So `:to` is being passed into the controller, but `User.find_by_email(params[:to])` is returning nil?  Are you sure the email you are passing in exists in the database?

Comment: Yes. none of the parameters are passing correctly meaning that if i replace @to with User.find_by_email(my@email.com) and have params[:topic], the topic of the message will not be what I set it to. The parameters are not being accepted or sent or something.

Comment: Can you please post your server logs to show what is passed in when you submit the form?  I'm guessing you need to access your params like: `@to = User.find_by_email(params[:message][:to])` since the form is nesting within the `@message` object but I can't be sure without seeing your server logs

Comment: @Planetpluto Please close out this question by hitting the checkmark next to my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure how to "close out" a question. Thank you though, I was able to solve the problem, instead of :message it was :acts-as-messagable

Answer (score 0):

It's because gem doesn't add the route, while form helper tries to generate send URL.
Check it with `rake routes`.

Comment: how do I add it to the routes? It says nothing about routes in the github

Comment: What version of Rails do you use?

Comment: I think you just uses it the wrong way.
`ActsAsMessageable::Message` is a child class of ActiveRecord::Base, but it's not supposed to be used like that.
If you really need to use it in your forms, override your form URL with required one.

Comment: Create custom form and use it to sent data and compose new message inside your controller. 
At least, that `example controller` doesn't give me another thoughts.